# Setting point color in excel C# is giving Invalid Parameter exception

Tags: c#, excel-interop

```
Excel.SeriesCollection seriesCollection = chartPage.SeriesCollection();
Excel.Series series1 = seriesCollection.NewSeries();
series1.XValues = activeSheet.Range["E1", "E3"];
series1.Values = activeSheet.Range["F1", "F3"];

series1.Points(0).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = Color.Green.ToArgb();
```

Gives a invalid parameter exception.

Here's the details:

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException was unhandled by user code
  HResult=-2146827284
  Message=Invalid Parameter
  Source=S
  ErrorCode=-2146827284
  StackTrace:
       at System.RuntimeType.ForwardCallToInvokeMember(String memberName, BindingFlags flags, Object target, Int32[] aWrapperTypes, MessageData& msgData)
       at Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Series.Points(Object Index)
       at OMSS.BobStats.DrawFractionChart(Worksheet activeSheet, ChartObjects xlCharts, Range xRange, Range yRange) in c:\Users\t-jasonj\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\BobStats\ExcelAddIn1\BobStats.cs:line 104
       at OMSS.BobStats.DrawCharts(Worksheet activeSheet, Range range, Int32 length) in c:\Users\t-jasonj\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\BobStats\ExcelAddIn1\BobStats.cs:line 66
       at OMSS.BobStats.ThisAddIn_Startup(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\Users\t-jasonj\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\BobStats\ExcelAddIn1\BobStats.cs:line 52
       at Microsoft.Office.Tools.AddInImpl.OnStartup()
       at Microsoft.Office.Tools.AddInImpl.AddInExtensionImpl.Microsoft.Office.Tools.EntryPoint.OnStartup()
       at Microsoft.Office.Tools.AddInBase.OnStartup()
       at OMSS.BobStats.FinishInitialization() in c:\Users\t-jasonj\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\BobStats\ExcelAddIn1\BobStats.Designer.cs:line 59
       at Microsoft.Office.Tools.AddInBase.Microsoft.Office.Tools.EntryPoint.FinishInitialization()
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Office.Runtime.DomainCreator.ExecuteCustomization.ExecutePhase(ExecutionPhases executionPhases)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Office.Runtime.DomainCreator.ExecuteCustomization.Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Office.Runtime.Interop.IExecuteCustomization2.ExecuteEntryPoints()
  InnerException:
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you either use

```
series1.Points(1).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(Color.Green);
```

or

```
series1.Points(1).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = Excel.XlRgbColor.rgbGreen
```

**Edit: Note that Points are 1 indexed not 0 indexed.**

Comment: Ah this worked. But as a note Points(0) doesn't work. Points are 1 indexed not 0 indexed. Took me forever to figure out ><

Comment: thank you but I've rewritten your code line, didn't noticed that, thanks again

Comment: Oh I edited your answer to reflect my change :P Didn't want to confuse other people who might have the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't like the A in ToArgb().  Use the & operator to get rid of it:

```
series1.Points(1).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = Color.Green.ToArgb() & 0xffffff;
```